# How to determine if an object is empty with rego language

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent, rego

In kuberntes OPA gatekeeper, I need to determine if there is `volumeName` defined in PVC object, like below code:

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "PersistentVolumeClaim",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {},
        "name": "pvc-test-mxh",
        "namespace": "default"
    },
    "spec": {
        "accessModes": [
            "ReadWriteOnce"
        ],
        "resources": {
            "requests": {
                "storage": "5Gi"
            }
        },
        "storageClassName": "csi-disk",
        "volumeName": "mxh-test"
    }
}
```

here, the `volumeName` is defined and belongs to normal behavior that it's allowed in the gatekeeper policy; while `volumeName` is missing here it would match to the violation. But how to write this policy, I tried `input.review.object.spec.volumeName == ""` or `count(input.review.object.spec.volumeName) <= 0`, seems like it didn't work, anyone could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally use the `not` keyword for that purpose:

```
not input.review.object.spec.volumeName
```

`not` will evaluate to true if `input.review.object.spec.volumeName` is undefined, and correspondingly to undefined if `input.review.object.spec.volumeName` is set.

Comment: I tried in this way but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes it does: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/vUQJrRQdgq